# Bitbucket webhook Jenkins сборка ветки с новым коммитом

Tags: bitbucket, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, jenkins-pipeline

Есть репа в Bitbucket в которой настроены webhooks для запуска выливки кода на сервер с определенной ветки. Но сейчас хочу перенастроить логику выливки таким образом что бы выливалась только та ветка в которую был сделан коммит. Покопавшись в документации репки не нашел четкой инструкции как решить мой кейс. Подскажите куда копать, возможно ли как то извлечь из приходящего хука имя ветки в которую пришел коммит и передать эту переменную в качестве параметра в джобу для аплоада кода?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут есть ответ, помню тоже сидел над такой задачкой https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011610/bitbucket-webhook-to-jenkins-with-branch-name

Comment: конечно я его тоже видел, но не получилось у меня. Сделал все как описано но выливка не запускается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не могу в коммент ответить...
смотри у меня такой вариант, в любую ветку пушаться изменения - вебхук триггерит джобу с тестами.

1)scm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)build environment:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) потом можно вывести:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В переменной ${GIT_BRANCH} - будет бранч, с ней дальше уже работай